# YTPlayerView doesn't play video when you click

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, youtube-api, ytplayerview

I am trying to use YTPlayerView in my Swift (2.x), iOS 9 project but I am only able to show the video preview with the play symbol. Nothing happens when you click the symbol.

```
playerView.loadWithVideoId("someId")
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug with some previous versions of the `YTPlayerView`.

Update your Podfile to point to the repo head and update the pod:

```
pod 'youtube-ios-player-helper', :git=>'https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper', :commit=>'head'
```

Then try calling `loadWithVideoId` again, or with an empty `playerVars` dictionary:

```
self.playerView.loadWithVideoId("U5vgRJ0zK6Y")
```

or

```
self.playerView.loadWithVideoId("U5vgRJ0zK6Y", playerVars: [:])
```